# Java: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am busy writing an algorithm that will scan a text file and add its contents into an array. However I keep getting an error message which says:

> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException"

I have read up on the java documents and learned that this error has something to do with the fact that I haven't set up my text file properly, however I do not understand how to fix it.

I have included my code and the contents of the text file:

```
String [] CardPictureNames = new String [16];   

    try { 
        Scanner car = new Scanner (new File("cardNames.txt")).useDelimiter("#");
        String CN = "";

        while(car.hasNext()){
            for(int j=0; j <= CardPictureNames.length; j++ ){ 
                CN = car.next();
                CardPictureNames[j] = CN;
            }
        }
        car.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MemoryForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"The file containing the names of the cards is missing.");
    }
```

Here are the contents of the text file:

```
2 of Clubs#
10 of Clubs#
Ace of Hearts#
Ace of Spades#
Joker#
King of Hearts#
Queen of Clubs#
Queen of Diamonds#
2 of Clubs#
10 of Clubs#
Ace of Hearts#
Ace of Spades#
Joker#
King of Hearts#
Queen of Clubs#
Queen of Diamonds#
```

Can someone please explain to me how I can fix this problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your while/for loop combo with this

```
for(int j=0; j <= CardPictureNames.length; j++ ){ 
        if (car.hasNext()) {
            CN = car.nextLine();
            CardPictureNames[j] = CN;
        }
}
```

What you are attempting to do is loop it twice. Which is unnecessary. The if statement is added to prevent the exception from happening by not running the code that gets the card names unless there is another line (which there isn't at the end)

Now I'm assuming there is a better way to do this. But this works. And the so called "better" way probably wouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Thanks Zachery, I really appreciate your help. I did manage to figure out a fix for myself as well. It turns out, all I had to do was change my original code from "<= CardPictureNames.length" into "< CardPictureNames.length"